# Несмотря/невзирая на то(,) что

Tags: запятые

Нужны ли те запятые?

1.1. Несмотря на то(,) что он был котом, он, этот Барс, был-таки умён.

1.2. Невзирая на то(,) что он был котом, он, этот Барс, был-таки умён.

2.1. Я мыл мокр до нитки, несмотря на то(,) что, казалось, дождь был не силён в тот таки денёк.

2.2. Я мыл мокр до нитки, невзирая на то(,) что, казалось, дождь был не силён в тот таки денёк.